# How to remove default date from VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to remov default date from VF page next to the box is this can be done
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need some CSS:

```
div.hideCurrDate span.dateInput span.dateFormat{
   display:none;
}
```

And HTML wrapper DIV:

```
<div class="hideCurrDate">
    <apex:inputField value="{!someDateVar}" id="yourDateField" />
</div>
```

Here is a page example that works for me:

```
<apex:page controller="myClass">

    <style>
        div.hideCurrDate span.dateInput span.dateFormat{
           display:none;
        }
    </style>

    <apex:form >

        <div class="hideCurrDate">
            <apex:inputField value="{!obj.Birthdate__c}" id="yourDateField" />
        </div>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: HI mastOr i tried the code but its not working

Comment: @rakesh Hi, i posted a new example of the page. That works for me.

Comment: Hi mastOr i have another issue im displaying some event fields on vf page but im not displaying the Time field on this page. when i save the record im getting the error msg.                              System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Time]: [Time]
Error is in expression '{!dosave}' in component <apex:page> in page bathing_solutions

Comment: to my  requirement i dont need this field on the page how can i sort it out

Comment: @rakesh If this is a required field - it must be filled out with a value. Go to your custom object and make this field not mandatory.

Comment: cant we manipulate this my customer dont want that field on the page

Comment: If you dont want this field to be a mandatory field - go to your custom object and edit this field: unselect "Required" checkbox.

Comment: but this is a Sobject And Standard \Field

Comment: I think you must fill this field out with a dummy value like "xxxx" or something else, because without value you cannot save a new record.